# Obtener 2 o mas registros que se tengan una diferencia menos a 10 min

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Tengo una tabla con datos movimientos de saldos, por ejemplo:

```
fecha    cuenta    monto
fecha1   cuenta1   1.00
fecha2   cuenta2   5.00
fecha3   cuenta2   3.00
```

Como obtener los registros duplicados con un lapso de tiempo menor a 10 min

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Con referencia a qué? ¿Tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: con referencia a la misma tabla, es decir, si hay un registro de la cuenta 1 a una determinada fecha y hay otro registro con la cuenta uno con otra fecha pero que no pase de 10 minutos referente a la fecha del otro registro, cabe señalar que puede haber un registro con la misma cuenta pero con una fecha mayor a minutos de diferencia

Comment: El problema es más complejo de lo que parece, lo resolvería al registrar el dato haciendo una comparación del último registro de la cuenta, de este modo obtengo ambas fechas, hago una resta y veo si cumple o no con esa diferencia de tiempo.

Comment: Para hacerlo en puro SQL, una opción sería tener ordenada la data por tiempo ASC o DESC, de la misma manera, agrupar por cuentas, recorrer cada row y comparar... Por el momento es lo único que se me ocurre. Espero estas ideas te sean de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Es necesario saber el motor de la base de datos en el cual se ejecutará la sentencia sql, y el tipo de dato de la columna `fecha`, la clave primaria de la tabla y el nombre para poder escribir una sentencia sql. Sin lo anterior no se puede escribir una solucion

Comment: @MauricioOrtega El motor es SQL Server Management Studio, fecha es datetime, la clave primaria es id y tipo bigint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes formular la tarea así: Quiero ver filas para que existe otra fila con una diferencia menos de 10 minutos. Esto traduce a `WHERE EXISTS` en SQL:

```
select *
from mi_tabla
where exists
(
  select null
  from mi_tabla otra
  where otra.cuenta = mi_table.cuenta
  and otra.fecha <> mi_table.fecha
  and abs(datediff(minute, otra.fecha, mi_table.fecha)) < 10
)
order by cuenta, fecha;
```

O puedes formular la tarea así: Quero ver filas para que la precedente o siguiente fila tiene una diferencia menos de 10 minutos. Esto traduce a `LAG` y `LEAD` en SQL:

```
select fecha, cuenta, monto
from
(
  select
    fecha, cuenta, monto,
    lag(fecha) over (partition by cuenta order by fecha) as pre,
    lead(fecha) over (partition by cuenta order by fecha) as sig
  from mi_tabla
)
where abs(datediff(minute, fecha, pre)) < 10
   or abs(datediff(minute, fecha, sig)) < 10
order by cuenta, fecha;
```

Esta segunda forma de escribir la consulta es más moderno y probablemente más rápido.

El index que recomiendo para las dos consultas es

```
create index idx on mi_tabla (cuenta, fecha);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!, funciono excelente